# Update embedded worksheet in ppt slide apache poi

Tags: apache-poi

I am trying to update an embedded excel file in a powerpoint slide, however I am not able to do it. I wonder if is even possible to update an existing excel embedded worksheet or I have to create it from scratch given the inputstream of the new file and then attach it?

This is what I have [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCRNT.png) .

Unique embedded file and trying to replace it with another file, doing this (Using apache poi 5.2.4
):

```
    PackagePart excelEmbedding = slideShow.getAllEmbeddedParts().get(0);
    InputStream is = excelEmbedding.getInputStream();
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(is);
    FileOutputStream newTestFileOut = new FileOutputStream(newTestFilePath);
    workbook.write(newTestFileOut);
    workbook.close();
```

In order to have this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCG0d.png)

Thanks for your answer.

Currently doing this code: [image]

Comment: Hi @AxelRichter could you please let me know if is possible? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @AxelRichter I just attached a picture of the current code in this initial question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask -> **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code gets a `XSSFWorkbook` from embedded `PackagePart` and writes that to an external file but not as embedded package part. Therefore, this code neither updates the embedded workbook nor replaces it with another one.

[PackagePart.getOutputStream](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/openxml4j/opc/PackagePart.html#getOutputStream--) provides access to an `OutputStream` from that `PackagePart`.

So updating the embedded workbook would be like so:

Get the `XSSFWorkbook` from embedded `PackagePart` using `XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(packagePart.getInputStream());`. Then do what is needed with that `XSSFWorkbook` after that write the changed `XSSFWorkbook` to output stream got via `packagePart.getOutputStream()`. Don't forget closing that output stream after writing.

Replacing the embedded workbook would be like so:

Get the embedded `PackagePart` and get a `XSSFWorkbook` from elsewhere. Then write the `XSSFWorkbook` to output stream got via `packagePart.getOutputStream()`. Don't forget closing that output stream after writing.

Complete Example to replace the embedded workbook:

```java
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart;

public class PPTXReplaceEmbeddedExcel {
         
 public static void main(String[] args)  {

  try ( XMLSlideShow slideShow = new XMLSlideShow(new FileInputStream("./TableSample.pptx"));
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./TableSampleNew.pptx"); ) {
  
   PackagePart firstEmbeddedExcelPackagePart = null;
   for (PackagePart packagePart : slideShow.getAllEmbeddedParts()) {
    System.out.println(packagePart.getContentType());
    if ("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet".equals(packagePart.getContentType())) {
     firstEmbeddedExcelPackagePart = packagePart;
    }
   }
  
   if (firstEmbeddedExcelPackagePart != null) {
    try ( FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("./Excel.xlsx");
          XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
          OutputStream os = firstEmbeddedExcelPackagePart.getOutputStream(); ) {
     // do something with workbook...
     workbook.write(os);
    }
   }
    
   slideShow.write(out);
  } catch (Exception ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Hi @AxelRichter thanks. I'm doing now this but no results yet, what am I doing wrong? I cannot close the package part because got an error

String newExcelToEmbed = "./test2.xlsx"; InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(newExcelToEmbed); XSSFWorkbook newExcelToReplace = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
PackagePart previousExcelFile = slideShow.getAllEmbeddedParts().get(0); OutputStream targetStream = previousExcelFile.getOutputStream();
IOUtils.copy(newExcelToReplace.getPackagePart().getInputStream(), targetStream); inputStream.close(); targetStream.close();
Thanks for your help;

Comment: @Adrian Duran: Provided complete example in my answer.