# Update embedded excel file in ppt slide with large amount of data apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to update an empty excel embedded in a ppt slide, and is working with low size excel files, however with excel file with more data is throwing an error: gc overhead limit exceeded updating xssfworkbook

The current code I have is this:

```
            PackagePart embeddedFile = null;
        for (PackagePart packagePart : ppt.getAllEmbeddedParts()) {
            if ("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet".equalsIgnoreCase(packagePart.getContentType())) {
                firstEmbeddedExcelPackagePart = packagePart;
            }
        }

        if (embeddedFile != null) {
            InputStream inputStream = getExcelInputStream();
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
            OutputStream os = firstEmbeddedExcelPackagePart.getOutputStream();
            workbook.write(os);
            workbook.close();
            os.close();
        }
```

Then I tried to solve the error by doing this update in one of the lines above, but got this new error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

```
.... 
SXSSFWorkbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream), 100, true, true);
...
```

Then tried to update jvm config in intellij by updating this value -Xmx8192m, but got the same first error.

Is there a way how to handle large sizes of excel file in order to update an existing embedded excel file in ppt slide (empty file) or the option is to create the file to embed instead of updating a template excel file?

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Hi @AxelRichter do you know if there is a way how to handle this scenario? Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

See [Error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393486/error-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded) for reasons of `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`.

> This message means that for some reason the garbage collector is
> taking an excessive amount of time ... and recovers very little memory
> in each run.

> The rare cases where I've seen this happen is where
> some code was creating tons of temporary objects and tons of
> weakly-referenced objects in an already very memory-constrained
> environment.

That is here the case too.

I guess the complete example of your code is something like my answer in [Update embedded worksheet in ppt slide apache poi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77734944/update-embedded-worksheet-in-ppt-slide-apache-poi/77735084#77735084).

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart;

public class PPTXReplaceEmbeddedExcel {
         
 public static void main(String[] args)  {

  try ( XMLSlideShow slideShow = new XMLSlideShow(new FileInputStream("./TableSample.pptx"));
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./TableSampleNew.pptx"); ) {
  
   PackagePart firstEmbeddedExcelPackagePart = null;
   for (PackagePart packagePart : slideShow.getAllEmbeddedParts()) {
    System.out.println(packagePart.getContentType());
    if ("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet".equals(packagePart.getContentType())) {
     firstEmbeddedExcelPackagePart = packagePart;
    }
   }
  
   if (firstEmbeddedExcelPackagePart != null) {
    try ( FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("./Excel.xlsx");
          XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
          OutputStream os = firstEmbeddedExcelPackagePart.getOutputStream(); ) {
     // do something with workbook...
     workbook.write(os);
    }
   }
    
   slideShow.write(out);
  } catch (Exception ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

There `XMLSlideShow slideShow = new XMLSlideShow(new FileInputStream("./TableSample.pptx"))` creates a [XMLSlideShow](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xslf/usermodel/XMLSlideShow.html) from a PowerPoint file in Office Open XML file format. That means unzipping the Office Open XML file format ZIP, reading the XML and creating tons of Java objects (Apache POI `XSLF` objects but also tons of `XMLBeans` created objects from Microsoft's XML schemes for PowerPoint files). After that `XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis)` does the same for a `XSSFWorkbook` from an Excel file in Office Open XML file format. That means unzipping the Office Open XML file format ZIP, reading the XML and creating tons of Java objects (Apache POI `XSSF` objects but also tons of `XMLBeans` created objects from Microsoft's XML schemes for Excel files).

After all we have tons of Java objects in memory for `XSLF`, `XSSF` and both kinds of low level Java objects created via `XMLBeans`  from Microsoft's XML schemes for PowerPoint and Excel.

That's memory and CPU consuming.

If it is only to update `firstEmbeddedExcelPackagePart` from whole content of an Excel file without manipulating the workbook, then creating a `XSSFWorkbook` is not necessary. Then you only should copy the Excel file content into `OutputStream` of the embedded package part. This at least saves having to create the `XSSFWorkbook`.

```
...
if (firstEmbeddedExcelPackagePart != null) {
 try ( FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("./Excel.xlsx");
       //XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
       OutputStream os = firstEmbeddedExcelPackagePart.getOutputStream(); ) {
  // do something with workbook...
  //workbook.write(os);
   fis.transferTo(os);
  
 }
}
...
```